# What happened to the bookmarks?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Yesterday, strangely enough, all my bookmarks were gone.

Instead, a new system was apparently active, where questions and answers could be saved and nested in categories.

This was a **great idea**, but suddenly all my previously saved bookmarks were lost.

Today apparently the old system was activated again (Why?).

The problem:

Now both the old Boomarks and the new bookmarks are gone.

What happened here?

Comment: Strange I had not noticed this, I confess I don't use bookmarks much. If the change was recent maybe they are in the process of migrating things. Give it some time to sort things out

Comment: Mines are also gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves-temporarily-disabled) on the main meta *bookmarks* are now called "saves", and have been temporarily disabled.

> Saves is now officially live on Stack Overflow and across Stack
> Exchange sites! The migration process will take some time to process
> as there are millions of bookmarked questions to migrate over. If
> you’re not seeing any questions you previously bookmarked, that means
> they haven’t been processed yet.

Do not know how long *temporary* is, but you will see them again.

Comment: OK, wonderful, has apparently been resolved. Now the new system is active and the bookmarks (now "Saves") seem to have been migrated indeed. I was just badly irritated for a moment because at first I thought it was a mistake.